# (Win7 Pro) Can't Copy Chinese Characters

Tags: windows-7, pdf, fonts, language, chinese

Recently installed Win7 Pro & I'm trying to copy Chinese characters from a PDF to notepad.  I am able to do this on 2 other laptops both running Win7 Pro. I've tried adding the keyboard, changing the location, changing the system locale.  I've also copied the font folders from my other laptops and installed the Office language pack OfficeLangPack_ChnSimp_x64 and the Adobe Reader extended font pack for Asian languages FontPack11009_XtdAlf_Lang.msi.

When I copied the Chinese characters from PDF to notepad it initially showed up as "é", but now it's showing up as Ø上}！.

On both the working machines and the non-working machine notepad is using Lucida Console, Western script, Regular, 10 point.

I also can't copy to any other program, including Notepad++, Word, or any web browsers.

PDF is hosted at http://www.rapidshare.com.cn/UXCoday

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so I found a solution that worked for me.

I opened the PDF in Chrome and was able to copy-paste the characters from there.  I still can't copy-paste from the Acrobat Reader app itself, but as long as I can copy the contents I don't really care where that PDF is being opened.

Comment: Have you installed the Extended Asian Language font pack for Adobe Reader?